# Creating a custom GtkCellRenderer with PyGobject

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject, cellrenderer

I'm in the process of writing a Gtk application. Up 'til know I have been using pygtk but because that has been deprecated in favor of PyGobject I have decided to make the switch. Back in the time of pygtk one could extend the gtk.GenericCellRenderer but this class is not longer present.

I have tried to find examples in python that uses the new API but I have failed. Can anyone show an example of a custom cell renderer that I could use as a starting point?

Comment: [here is the almost same question with correct answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496322/overriding-virtual-methods-in-pygobject

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Gtk+ does not have any class called GtkGenericCellRenderer, is PyGtk exclusive.
Since PyGObject binding is virtually the same than the C API, because the introspection technology, I suggest to use GtkCellRenderer, present in Gtk+.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyCellRenderer(Gtk.CellRenderer):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.CellRenderer.__init__(self)
```

Comment: That I know, the issu is that the GtkGenericCellRenderer added a number of nice method that would make it simpler to create a custom one. My problem is that I just have experience doing so and all the How To for python are using the old bindings.

Comment: `gtk.GenericCellRenderer` was deprecated on PyGtk, you should to override the methods provided by Gtk.CellRenderer such as `render`, `activate` and `start_editing`, you need to see the documentation of this methods on the C Gtk+ documentation since the documentation generator for PyGObject still in development.