# Overriding virtual methods in PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, virtual-functions

I'm trying to implement the [Heigh-for-width Geometry Management](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#geometry-management) in GTK with Python for my custom Widget. My widget is a subclass from `Gtk.DrawingArea` and draws some parts of an Image.

As I understood the GTK Docs (link above) I have to implement the following 4 methods:

- GtkWidgetClass.get_preferred_width()
- GtkWidgetClass.get_preferred_height()
- GtkWidgetClass.get_preferred_height_for_width()
- GtkWidgetClass.get_preferred_width_for_height()

Now wondering where to implement this in Python.

I tried this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
class Patch(Gtk.DrawingArea):
  def __init__(self, model, image, position):
    super(Patch,self).__init__()
    #…

  def get_preferred_width(self, *args, **kargs):
    print("test")

  def get_preferred_height(self, *args, **kargs):
    print("test")

  def get_preferred_width_for_height(self, *args, **kargs):
    print("test")

  def get_preferred_height_for_width(self, *args, **kargs):
    print("test")
```

But the methods don't get called. In C you define the functions and set it to the widget like this:

```
static void
my_widget_get_preferred_height (GtkWidget *widget, gint *minimal_height,
                                gint *natural_height)
{
  /* ... */
}
  /* ... */

static void
my_widget_class_init (MyWidgetClass *class)
{
  /* ... */
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (class);
  widget_class->get_preferred_height = my_widget_get_preferred_height;
  /* ... */
}
```

How is this done in Python?

Comment: Note that pyGObject has been deprecated in favor of GObject-Introspection.

Comment: Isn't PyGObject the way to use GObject-Introspection with Python? Did you mean PyGTK is deprecated in favor of PyGObject?

Comment: @liberforce: Confusingly, the Python implementation of GObject Introspection is also called PyGObject. It was called PyGI for a while, but this seems to be the official name now. The old PyGObject was part of PyGTK which is now deprecated. (But the way of overriding virtual methods was the same, I believe.)

Comment: @ptomato: Wow, you're right: http://live.gnome.org/PyGI ! Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to name the methods like `do_virtual_method`:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
class Patch(Gtk.DrawingArea):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Patch,self).__init__()

  def do_get_preferred_width(self):
    print("test")
    return 100, 100

  def do_get_preferred_height(self):
    print("test")
    return 100, 100

win = Gtk.Window()
win.add(Patch())
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Note that you also have to return the values that the virtual method requires you to return, otherwise you'll get a cryptic error.

Comment: To implement the Height-for-width you must actually override `do_get_request_mode`, `do_get_preferred_height`, `do_get_preferred_width`, `do_get_preferred_width_for_height` and `do_get_preferred_height_for_width`